# WF_RULE_NOT_EVALUATED..Workflow not getting evaluated

Tags: apex, workflow

I built the following WFR - Field Update.

[image]

The requirement was straightforward.

The Sub Status of a case has to be set to a particular value when the record which is getting evaluated meets criteria.

But for some reason I observed that this WFR does not even get fired.

Then I did log and I found out the following statement

```
12:37:41.416 (3416016358)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Case: 00358077 50011000003tFzQ]|Update Search Sub Status|01Q1100000056yG|ON_CREATE_OR_TRIGGERING_UPDATE
12:37:41.416 (3416258427)|WF_RULE_NOT_EVALUATED
```

I am not able to understand why this WFR wont get evaluated.

Can someone throw me some pointers as to where I should be looking at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind..I figured it out.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2012/09/let%E2%80%99s-be-clear-workflow-rule-evaluation-criteria.html

From the above doc, it is said that WFR will be executed ONLY if the updated record which did not meet the criteria BEFORE meets the criteria NOW after the changes. Kinda tricky :)